# stored procedures and using tsql functions in parameters calls

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Environment sql server 2005 sp3

I have a stored proc that takes an INT as input. I want to CAST a CHAR to an INT during the call to the stored proc. it seems I cannot do that. I get a syntax error before @foo. I do not see it can someone help me find it please.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testme
@test AS INT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @TEST
END

    DECLARE @foo AS CHAR(6)
set @foo = '11test'
EXEC testMe @test = CAST(Substring(@foo,1,2) as int)
```

Comment: @dunc,@sqlmenance I have updated the question to reflect my problem better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first off all, you can't cast '11test' as an int

second, if the value can be converted to an int, you don't need to cast, an implicit cast will happen

```
DECLARE @foo AS CHAR(6)
set @foo = '2'


EXEC testMe @test =@foo
```

If you want to test if it can be converted to an int, grab the IsInt function from here: [IsNumeric, IsInt, IsNumber](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/isnumeric-isint-isnumber) and use that to test before making the proc call

EDIT

here is how you can do it

```
DECLARE @foo AS CHAR(6)
set @foo = '11test'
SET @foo = CAST(Substring(@foo,1,2) as int)

EXEC testMe @test = @foo
```

you can't pass functions to procs, this is why GETDATE() doesn't work either, either use an intermediate variable or cast back to the same variable

Comment: why cant i do it inline with the stored proc call?

Comment: Not allowed, could be because the function is non deterministic but I am not sure. From books on line `You cannot specify a function name as a parameter default value or as the value passed to a parameter when executing a procedure.`

Comment: is this the link you got that information at?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189915(v=SQL.90).aspx

if not can you supply me with that link. Thanks for finding this!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a char field to int when it contains non-numeric characters.

I would suggest creating a function that loops through the chars and removes any that are non-numeric.